# Back button and layout id detection

Tags: android, toast

I'm trying to have my app display a toast message when "Back" is pressed when R.layout.main.xml is displayed, but not display the message from any other layout.xml . Also, when any other layout is displayed, I want it to return to the previous screen (like a back button should). If I left the back button default, whenever you pressed it, it would exit the application from any layout screen.
Here is my current code..... it keeps force closing and I cant figure out why:

```
private Toast toast;
private long lastBackPressTime = 0;


@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    View thisView = getCurrentFocus();
    int screen = thisView.getId();
    if (screen == R.layout.main)
    {
        if (this.lastBackPressTime < System.currentTimeMillis() - 4000) 
        {
            toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press BACK once more to close this application", 4000);
            toast.show();
            this.lastBackPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (toast != null) 
            {
                toast.cancel();
            }
             super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    if (screen != R.layout.main)
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "force close". Also, your code will never work, as the ID of a `View` is not the ID of a layout file.

Answer (score 0):

In my apps I'm using constants for each layout and a `currentView` variable. Each time I change the content view I reassign this variable, so I'm always aware of where I'm currently being. Hope this helps you.